# Pointers to Class Members into a class with a private constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, language-lawyer, private-constructor

Lets say that I have a class with a private constructor and that class will be used to represent a single object. Lets say that I have some non-static members that I want to access without using the scope resolution operator. I've noticed that I can achieve this by creating a pointer to the class type to do so. I was wondering why can I declare pointers to that class even if the default constructor is private? Here is an example program.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


class OnlyOne{
    public:
    void Location(){
        std::cout<<10<<std::endl;
        
    }
    private:
    OnlyOne();
};
int main()
{
    //does not work Location() is not a static member
    //OnlyOne::Location();
     
      // doesn't work because default constructor is private.
     //OnlyOne one;
    //one.Location();
    
    
    OnlyOne* two=nullptr;
    two->Location();
}
```

I've been looking online to see if I could find an answer and haven't been able to get what I'm looking for.

Comment: you can declare pointers of types that don't even have a constructor, like a union. declaring a pointer is one thing, but instantiating is another thing.

Comment: Note: You may find `OnlyOne* two=nullptr; two->Location();` appears to run as expected. One of the nigh-infinite possible manifestations of [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) is the expected behaviour. Truly nasty  stuff, UB because it's easy to prove that you have it and very hard to prove that you don't. In this case `Location` does not use the `OnlyOne` it's been invoked on, never uses `this`, so the program may never notice that has a bad `this`.

Comment: If I understand correctly the solution given by Ali Askari solves this problem by using the Singleton pattern .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you declare a pointer of some type, that type doesn't have to be constructible. In fact, that type doesn't even have to be complete. So, this line:

```
OnlyOne* two = nullptr;
```

is perfectly fine.

Note that this line:

```
two->Location();
```

invokes undefined behavior, since there is no object pointed at by `two`, and so there is no object on which you can call the `Location` member function.

In fact, since this type is not constructible, `two` could never point at a valid object. You have to provide a way to construct such an object, either by providing a public constructor, or by having a static member function, that constructs and returns such an object.

Comment: Would   two->Location() still have undefined behavior if I changed **void location()** to **OnlyOne* Location()** and and the return statement to **return (OnlyOne*)10**?

Comment: That would allow you to return a `OnlyOne*`, but you cannot call `Location` without a valid `OnlyOne` instance in the first place. Also note that `return (OnlyOne*)10` is lying to the compiler. If you lie to the compiler to eliminate a compiler error, all you've done is move the error from compile time to run time where it could be harder to find. You need a valid `OnlyOne`, and address 10 almost certainly does not hold a `OnlyOne`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use singleton pttern to implement classes that have private constructor:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


class OnlyOne{
    public:

    static OnlyOne* instance() {
        static OnlyOne obj;
        return &obj;
    }

    void Location(){
        std::cout<<10<<std::endl;
        
    }
    private:
    OnlyOne() { }
};
int main()
{
    //does not work Location() is not a static member
    //OnlyOne::Location();
     
      // doesn't work because default constructor is private.
     //OnlyOne one;
    //one.Location();
    
    
    OnlyOne* two=OnlyOne::instance();
    two->Location();
}
```